# Perl script for getting inet from ip command

Tags: perl

I am trying to get the inet using ip command it is working fine on cmd prompt but if i add it in perl script, it is not executing as expected. Script is below:-

```
ip.pl

use strict;
my $a = `ip -f inet addr show eth0| grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+'`;
chomp($a);
print $a;
```

Executing above with "perl a.pl" returns nothing but "ip -f inet addr show eth0| grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+'" returns inet value.
How to get it executed using perl script?

Comment: perl inet.pl 
Unrecognized escape \K passed through at inet.pl line 3.
Unrecognized escape \d passed through at inet.pl line 3.

Comment: Try `my $a = qx'ip -f inet addr show eth0| grep -Po "inet \K[\d.]+"'`

Answer (score 6):

Turn on [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings) to get a hint:

```
Unrecognized escape \K passed through at ./1.pl line 5.
Unrecognized escape \d passed through at ./1.pl line 5.
```

Single quotes inside backticks aren't nested, you need to backslash the backslashes:

```
my $a = `ip -f inet addr show eth0| grep -Po 'inet \\K[\\d.]+'`;
```

Using `$a` for a lexical variable is wrong, it can cause weird bugs when [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort) is later used which uses `$a` as a special variable. Use a more meaningful name.

Moreover, calling `grep` from Perl is usually not needed, you can match the string in Perl itself:

```
my ($ip) = `ip -f inet addr show eth0` =~ /inet ([\d.]+)/;
```

or

```
my ($ip) = `ip -f inet addr show eth0` =~ /inet \K[\d.]+/g;
```